# FormMouseDown behind components

Tags: delphi

I noticed that FormMouseDown is not fired when there are any components placed in form and I click the location of e.g. Tlabel?

How can I make the Form mouse events (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove) to trigger always?

Comment: Use `TApplication.OnMessage`.

Comment: Sounds too heavy, I want to adjust only the components inside this one form...

Comment: The VCL does not really support what you are asking for.  You have to either assign `OnMouse...` events to every relevant component individually, or else use the `OnMessage` event to process every mouse window message before it is dispatched for processing, or use a thread-local mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Comment: can I make a transparent panel in front of everything to do this?

Comment: @Tom Clicks go right through a transparent control. That's what transparent means in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would appear to have a couple of options:

1. Arrange that every control on your form notifies the form when it process mouse messages.
2. Use a global mechanism, such as `TApplication.OnMessage`, to be notified of mouse messages before they are dispatched to controls and surfaced as events of those controls.

Of these two options, the first is an unmitigated disaster. The second is simple to implement, especially if you use a `TApplicationEvents` object to turn the application object's events into multi-cast dispatch.

Comment: Would this work:
      for i:= 0 to controlcount do begin
       components[i].OnMouseDown := formmousedown;
       components[i].OnMouseMove := formmousemove;

Comment: No. `TComponent` doesn't have those events. I guess they are introduced in `TControl`. So iterate recursively over `Controls[]`. Of course the controls can no longer use those events for their own needs.  For the life of me I can't understand why you reject the really simple solution.

Comment: @Tom - You'd additionally need to adjust mouse position, simple event assignment wouldn't cut it.